# Latex - Uncomplete vertical line on tabular

Tags: latex, tabular

I'm trying to make a bit tricky table in Latex using tabular, I wrote the following code :

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        n° structure & n° hexagone & valeur circuit & $R(K_i)$ & $E(B)$\\
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{$K_1$} & $h_1$ & $R_1$ & \multirow{3}{*}{$2R_1 + R_2 = 1.984$} & \multirow{12}{*}{$\frac{6R_1 + 4R_2 + 2R_3}{4} = 1.5995$}\\
                           & $h_2$ & $R_1$ & \\
                           & $h_3$ & $R_2$ & \\
        \cline{1-4}
        \multirow{3}{*}{$K_2$} & $h_1$ & $R_1$ & \multirow{3}{*}{$R_1 + R_2 + R_3 = 1.215$} \\
                           & $h_2$ & $R_2$ & \\
                           & $h_3$ & $R_3$ & \\
        \cline{1-4}
        \multirow{3}{*}{$K_3$} & $h_1$ & $R_2$ & \multirow{3}{*}{$2R_1 + R_2 = 1.984$} \\
                           & $h_2$ & $R_1$ & \\
                           & $h_3$ & $R_1$ & \\
        \cline{1-4}
        \multirow{3}{*}{$K_4$} & $h_1$ & $R_3$ & \multirow{3}{*}{$R_1 + R_2 + R_3 = 1.215$} \\
                           & $h_2$ & $R_2$ & \\
                           & $h_3$ & $R_1$ & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

And I got the following output, I really don't understand why the last vertical line isn't complete :

[image]

Does someone known the origin of the problem ?
Cordialy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table would look much more professional if you would not use vertical lines. See e.g. the documentation of the `booktabs` package for more information about creating good looking tables.

If you insist on vertical lines, you must make sure that each row has the same number of cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        n° structure & n° hexagone & valeur circuit & $R(K_i)$ & $E(B)$\\
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{$K_1$} & $h_1$ & $R_1$ & \multirow{3}{*}{$2R_1 + R_2 = 1.984$} & \multirow{12}{*}{$\frac{6R_1 + 4R_2 + 2R_3}{4} = 1.5995$}\\
                           & $h_2$ & $R_1$ & & \\
                           & $h_3$ & $R_2$ & & \\
        \cline{1-4}
        \multirow{3}{*}{$K_2$} & $h_1$ & $R_1$ & \multirow{3}{*}{$R_1 + R_2 + R_3 = 1.215$}  &\\
                           & $h_2$ & $R_2$ & & \\
                           & $h_3$ & $R_3$ & & \\
        \cline{1-4}
        \multirow{3}{*}{$K_3$} & $h_1$ & $R_2$ & \multirow{3}{*}{$2R_1 + R_2 = 1.984$}  &\\
                           & $h_2$ & $R_1$ & & \\
                           & $h_3$ & $R_1$ & & \\
        \cline{1-4}
        \multirow{3}{*}{$K_4$} & $h_1$ & $R_3$ & \multirow{3}{*}{$R_1 + R_2 + R_3 = 1.215$}  &\\
                           & $h_2$ & $R_2$ & & \\
                           & $h_3$ & $R_1$ & & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For information, with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, the vertical rules will be drawn even if you don't put all the ampersands (`&`) in a row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[vlines]
\Hline
        \no structure & \no hexagone & valeur circuit & $R(K_i)$ & $E(B)$\\
\Hline
        \Block{3-1}{$K_1$} & $h_1$ & $R_1$ & \Block{3-1}{$2R_1 + R_2 = 1.984$} & \Block{12-1}{$\frac{6R_1 + 4R_2 + 2R_3}{4} = 1.5995$}\\
                           & $h_2$ & $R_1$ \\
                           & $h_3$ & $R_2$ \\
\Hline
        \Block{3-1}{$K_2$} & $h_1$ & $R_1$ & \Block{3-1}{$R_1 + R_2 + R_3 = 1.215$}  &\\
                           & $h_2$ & $R_2$ \\
                           & $h_3$ & $R_3$ \\
\Hline
        \Block{3-1}{$K_3$} & $h_1$ & $R_2$ & \Block{3-1}{$2R_1 + R_2 = 1.984$}  &\\
                           & $h_2$ & $R_1$ \\
                           & $h_3$ & $R_1$ \\
\Hline
        \Block{3-1}{$K_4$} & $h_1$ & $R_3$ & \Block{3-1}{$R_1 + R_2 + R_3 = 1.215$}  &\\
                           & $h_2$ & $R_2$ \\
                           & $h_3$ & $R_1$ \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

However, like Sam Cater, I recommend a design of the table with `booktabs`.